# How do I install biopython in anaconda?

Tags: python, syntax, anaconda, biopython

I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

while trying to install biopython using the following command.

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython
```

Could you please help me install biopython in anaconda (3) ?

Comment: You're supposed to put that command into the terminal, not the python interpreter.

Comment: Hahahahaha sorry this is the funniest comment ever, +1, and yes he is right you install it through command line

Comment: But after installation, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'biopython

Comment: did you try importing it via `import Bio`?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and export your path to anaconda:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then type:

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython
```

Answer (score 3):

Package maintainers recommend using (in the terminal):

```
conda install -c conda-forge biopython
```

> We deliberately recommend using Biopython from the conda-forge channel, as this is usually up to date and covers Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. The default Conda channel does have Biopython, but is often out of date.
>   https://biopython.org/wiki/Packages

Answer (score 2):

Install Anaconda Navigator, go to "`Environments`" and select the appropriate environment (base or your own) and click "`not installed`". Scroll down to `biopython` click the box and then install...

Answer (score 0):

Team, I want to point out. If you use VS, you can work around any conda issue by going to the appropriated path and use .\pip install biopython