# Installing biopython: can't match required version of mkl

Tags: python, conda, biopython

I tried to install biopython on Linux Mint 19.3. I got an error message; package mkl==2020.0-166 was missing. I was able to downgrade to that version and tried again, but conda still claims the required version is missing. The list output shows: 'mkl [version] 2020.0 [build] 166'. I don't seem to understand how to give biopython the specific version it needs.

I found the question, [How do I install biopython in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117685/how-do-i-install-biopython-in-anaconda)
 which is closely related. I tried installing from the conda-forge cahnnel without success. Navigator also gave me the same error.

Here is the information about my system and the results I got:

** information pulled because I couldn't format it right.**

Comment: I tried to include more info, not code but terminal output. I don't know how to get past the malformatted code issue? -- should be pre-formatted but not code.

Comment: Can you include the information unformatted?

Comment: Here is part of it. I need to know how to do <pre> that's not code.  $ conda install biopython
...
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - mkl==2020.0-166

$ conda list mkl
# packages in environment at /home/bc/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
mkl                       2020.0                      166

Comment: And here's the list of mkl related packages:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
mkl                       2020.0                      166  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0